# I want to using multiple VMs and multiple NICs

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization, nic

I have a windows machine with virtualbox running and 3 NICs [eth0/eth1/eth2]. Eth0 is connected to ISP. Other 2 are connected to each other through a switch. [yes, it is a switch, yes I need it there]

I have 2 Ubuntu VMs. I want each VM to own one of the NICs[eth1/eth2] and be able to communicate through the switch only [not internally bridged]. Eventually, I will use the data coming out for tests... but for today, I need to get the interfaces communicating [I don't need to understand why it is faster/better to use the internal bridge, etc. I need to have data come out of eth1 and go back into eth2]

------ EDIT 1

I have tried to implement the solution someone described below. I am attaching a screenshot showing the 2 VMs and windows eth configurations.
Note that in windows, ETH0 is typically attached to ISP with a proper address and the 2 ETH0 in the VMs use NAT to connect out and collect updates, as needed.

Well, I can't post an image. That's just great.

Windows machine:

```
NIC1 is DHCP to ISP
NIC2 is set IP 10.10.20.101 / subnet 255.255.255.0 / no gateway
NIC3 is set IP 10.10.20.201 / subnet 255.255.255.0 / no gateway
VBOX host only adapt #1 is set IP 10.10.20.100 / subnet 255.255.255.0 / no gateway
VBOX host only adapt #2 is set IP 10.10.20.200 / subnet 255.255.255.0 / no gateway
```

VM#1:

```
ETH0 is set to DHCP [receives 10.0.3.15 address]
ETH1 is set IP 10.10.20.5 / subnet 255.255.255.0 / no gateway
ETH2 is set IP 10.10.20.6 / subnet 255.255.255.0 / no gateway
```

VM#2:

```
ETH0 is set to DHCP [receives 10.0.3.15 address]
ETH1 is set IP 10.10.20.2 / subnet 255.255.255.0 / no gateway
ETH2 is set IP 10.10.20.3 / subnet 255.255.255.0 / no gateway
```

I can put some info about the windows network settings if needed as well as the info about the set up in virtualbox if it helps.

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: I dont't know what are you trying to test, but if you are trying to emulate a real network with real different machines, take a look at PCI passthough (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough). It'll be the closer thing to two real different machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by bridging the virtual NIC of VM1 to eth1 and that of VM2 to eth2.

Both settings are to be applied in the properties of the VMs on the host.

Both VMs need IP addresses from your home network (easiest through DHCP)

Answer (score 0):

Set all VM NIC to Bridge mode then they will communicate through switch only.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail please ?